# Disable/enable text selection in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

We've got a project, were we disabling text selection to all body content. So the solution for this is CSS styles for normal browsers (like `user-select: none`) and workaround for IE (like `document.body.onselectstart = function () { return false; }`).

So the problem is: how to enable text selection in some div-elements in IE? And how to do it simple and quickly?

Comment: Can't those div's properties be overridden from the start?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the easiest way would be to reverse your logic and only apply this rule to elements that aren't supposed to be able to have their text selected. Problem with applying this rule to the whole body is that any child elements then already receive this overridden event from their parent (body) element, and the way to re-initialize `onselectstart` event isn't as easy as some seem to have assumed with their answers here. In your case, I would remove this rule for the whole body and then only apply it to the individual elements that don't have any children where the overriding rule must not apply.

**Example:**

```
<body>
  this is some text that is selectable
  <div style='-o-user-select: none;
              -webkit-user-select: none;
              -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
              -khtml-user-select: none;
              -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;' 
       onselectstart='return false;'
       unselectable='on'>
    this is some text that's not selectable
  </div>  
</body>
```

**>** see working demo on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pXYN/4/)**

---

*Note that some individual properties listed aren't supported yet and I've added them anyway for future-proofing purposes. The rule-set is compiled in a way to support as many different browsers as possible. Some will obey CSS styling, some need a JavaScript hack (IE < 10) and Opera browsers obey to a special element property (see below).*

**EDIT:** Added support for Opera browsers (`unselectable='on'`)

Comment: You've misunderstood me. See in this fiddle what I mean, and this will not work in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/6pXYN/85/

Comment: unselectable='on' worked like a charm even on old versions of IE

Answer (score 2):

```
<div onselectstart='return true;'>blablabla</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    document.body.onselectstart = function (event) {
    if(event.srcElement.parentNode.id == 'mydiv')//you may need to loop if the parentNode is 
    {                                            //not a div element
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

note: disabling javascript will enable the user to select text

I have updated the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mehavel/6pXYN/5/)

Comment: @TildalWave please check the above script. The 'onselectstart' inline will not work because binding the 'onselectstart' to body will take precedence over the inline function call.

Comment: I don't need to check it as I know this corrected code would work, good job! A slight reservation though that this only selects a single element (first out of possible many) and not all with an ID of 'mydiv' (ID should be a unique value anyway). It might simply be easier to reverse the rule logic, especially if the contents in question are generated dynamically in some server-side script. You could still improve on your selector code and make it a bit more generic, perhaps with a `for each` loop matching elements by some property of theirs? Cheers!

Comment: @TildalWave Thanks for the suggestion. yeah of-course it can be improved , just provided a simpler solution. I understand this wont handle all the scenarios :)

Comment: It would be nice if you can improve your answer, if you find the time for it, yes. It's a different approach and just as valid as the one I suggested, and other users might find it even more useful. I was actually thinking along the same lines at first, while reading OP's question, but have decided on a different approach as I thought your solution was already suggested (but later discovered they wouldn't work the way they were initially proposed). I'm deleting my first comment to your answer as it's no longer relevant ;)

Comment: Also, if you decide to improve your answer, take note that this current version of your code only works properly in Chrome (and compatible) due to `onselectstart` property not forwarding events through a function parameter like you did in other browsers. In IE a solution could be to omit the `event` parameter and then select an active element with: `if(window.event.srcElement.id == 'mydiv'){`. This however still won't work in Firefox or Opera and those need another approach. If there's a single approach compatible with all of them, I honestly wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery

```
$("body").disableSelection();
```

Comment: The question was how to enable text selection in some div-elements in IE (while others remain disabled). Your code only disables selection on all elements contained within the document body, which was obviously already achieved.